# Google Apps Script to open a URL based on a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell B2 which shows dynamic hyperlinks depending on user's selection and I would like to use that cell as a reference to my script (which opens url on a button).
How can I modify this script in order to get the link from the B2 cell?

```
//change the value of url to your desired url.
function openUrl( url="https://google.com" ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `I would like to use that cell as a reference to my script (which opens url on a button).` and `How can I modify this script in order to get the link from the B2 cell?`, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function openUrl( url="https://google.com" ){
```

#### To:

```
function openUrl(){
  var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getValue();
```

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Comment: @mrfrankito Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.